# Numeric properties that are returned as string by SPARQL

Tags: sparql, rdf, semantic-web, ontology, linked-data

I'm having a problem with SPARQL when dealing with numeric data types.

I have an ontology (http://cabas.ugr.es/ontology/ugr) in which I have defined a pair of properties that represent the number of students who are of a particular sex:

```
<http://cabas.ugr.es/ontology/ugr#hombres>
                     a owl:DatatypeProperty, owl:FunctionalProperty, rdf:Property ;
  rdfs:label
    "hombres"@es,
    "men"@en ;
  rdfs:comment
    "Número de estudiantes hombres."@es,
    "Number of male students."@en ;
  rdfs:range xsd:nonNegativeInteger ;
  rdfs:isDefinedBy <http://cabas.ugr.es/ontology/ugr#> ;
  owl:sameAs <http://cabas.ugr.es/ontology/ugr#hombres> ;
  owl:inverseOf <http://cabas.ugr.es/ontology/ugr#mujeres> ;
  ns1:term_status "stable" .

<http://cabas.ugr.es/ontology/ugr#mujeres>
                     a owl:DatatypeProperty, owl:FunctionalProperty, rdf:Property ;
  rdfs:label
    "mujeres"@es,
    "women"@en ;
  rdfs:comment
    "Número de estudiantes mujeres."@es,
    "Number of female students."@en ;
  rdfs:range xsd:nonNegativeInteger ;
  rdfs:isDefinedBy <http://cabas.ugr.es/ontology/ugr#> ;
  owl:sameAs <http://cabas.ugr.es/ontology/ugr#mujeres> ;
  owl:inverseOf <http://cabas.ugr.es/ontology/ugr#hombres> ;
  ns1:term_status "stable" .
```

I have a SPARQL endpoint mounted on Virtuoso (http://cabas.ugr.es:8890/sparql), in which I enter for example the following query:

```
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX ugr: <http://cabas.ugr.es/ontology/ugr#>

SELECT ?X ?titulacion ?rama ?hombres ?mujeres
WHERE {
  ?X ugr:Titulación ?titulacion .
  ?X ugr:RamaConocimiento ?rama .
  ?X ugr:hombres ?hombres .
  ?X ugr:mujeres ?mujeres
}
```

(Which would correspond with [this link](http://cabas.ugr.es:8890/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fcabas.ugr.es&query=PREFIX+rdfs%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23%3E%0D%0APREFIX+ugr%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fcabas.ugr.es%2Fontology%2Fugr%23%3E%0D%0A%0D%0ASELECT+%3FX+%3Ftitulacion+%3Frama+%3Fhombres+%3Fmujeres%0D%0AWHERE+%7B%0D%0A++%3FX+ugr%3ATitulaci%C3%B3n+%3Ftitulacion+.%0D%0A++%3FX+ugr%3ARamaConocimiento+%3Frama+.%0D%0A++%3FX+ugr%3Ahombres+%3Fhombres+.%0D%0A++%3FX+ugr%3Amujeres+%3Fmujeres%0D%0A%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=0&debug=on))

It returns all the records, but the fields **"hombres"** and **"mujeres"** returns them to me as if it were a string instead of a numeric value, so for example it is impossible to apply a filter like `FILTER (?hombres > 500)`. Any idea what I'm wrong about?

By the way, the ontology and the resource with the values are accessible through these links:

- Ontology:

  - Turtle Format:

    - http://cabas.ugr.es/ontology/ugr
    - http://cabas.ugr.es/ontology/ugr.ttl
  - RDF/XML Format:

    - http://cabas.ugr.es/ontology/ugr.rdf
- Resource:

  - Turtle Format:

    - http://cabas.ugr.es/resources/MatriculasGrado1516
    - http://cabas.ugr.es/resources/matriculas_grado_1516.ttl
  - RDF/XML Format:

    - http://cabas.ugr.es/resources/matriculas_grado_1516.rdf

Comment: Defining the range of a property is not enough. this has also to be reflected in the instance data by adding the datatype to each literal: `:x :hombres "352"` -> `:x :hombres "352"^^xsd:nonNegativeInteger`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to treat the numbers as numbers, you need to define them as such.

Right now you define them as strings:

```
<http://cabas.ugr.es/resources/MatriculasGrado1516#21>
  ns0:hombres "91" ;
  ns0:mujeres "68" .
```

To define them as integers, you need to set their type to `xsd:integer`:

```
<http://cabas.ugr.es/resources/MatriculasGrado1516#21>
  ns0:hombres "91"^^xsd:integer ;
  ns0:mujeres "68"^^xsd:integer .
```

Strings can also be cast to integer in queries, if needed. For example:

```
FILTER(xsd:integer(?hombres) > 500)
```